# Efficient way to handle 429 error while processing request in batches on multiple instances

Tags: batch-processing, multiple-instances, http-status-code-429, rate-limiting

I have batches of `500 messages`. And to send them I am using the external API which allows sending only 1 message at a time. Also, they have a rate limit of `10/seconds`.

If there is a single instance then I can handle the rate limit by adding a delay between the API calls. But in my case number of instance are not fixed. It totally depends upon the traffic I receive.

Let's say I have `10 instances` running and they are processing messages in batches of 500 messages. So, I have to process 5000 messages in total. But the rate limit is `10/seconds` so if all the instance invokes the same API with the same credentials then the rate limit get exceeded after a single API call of every instance.

When It will try to send the second message then they will get the `429 error` as the rate limit is exceeded.

Now, I want to make sure that combining all the 10 instances will only send the `10` messages per second. How can I implement it?

Any better suggestions or recommendations are appreciated!!

Comment: This is an interesting problem, I 'd love to know if you came up with a solution!